# Run cron job in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cpanel

Of-course, this is one similar question. But i tried with many solutions. Still i couldn't make it right.

I need to setup cron job in CPanel. Following is the command, which i gave to run cron job.

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=trigger > /dev/null 2>&1

wget -O /dev/null http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=processing > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it is not working and also i need to execute mysql query accordingly in the same panel.

This is the command which i set to run the cron job.

> mysql -u username -p password db_name < /home/user/cron.sql

But it is not working. Can any one please give an idea / suggestions? How to run cron job in cpanel?

Comment: try this : `CURL http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=trigger`

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working.

Comment: Then, what is the error?

Comment: How to find error? and where it will be?

Comment: Set the email address while you are creating a cron job. On that mail id you will got the mail.

Comment: This is the error. /bin/sh: CURL: command not found

Comment: Ok. Now check `phpinfo` CURL is enable or not on server.

Comment: Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/domain/public_html/phpinfo.php

Comment: I have used GET http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=… > /dev/null. Its working now. Then how to run mysql query in cron job? Please give me any idea.. This is CPanel..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your hosting is running a linux machine, because these commands are not windows compatible.

If you have ssh access then try to run this command :

`$ which wget`

This will give you the full path of wget if it is installed. Using that path you can modify your cron to be something like :

```
/full/path/to/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=trigger > /dev/null 2>&1

/full/path/to/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=processing > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To run mysql queries from bash :

```
mysql --user=username --password=password --database=database --execute="SELECT * FROM mytable;"
```

Comment: I have used 
GET http://www.domainname.com?import_key=-lIkUvA-r&import_id=4&action=trigger > /dev/null. Its working now. Then how to run mysql query in cron job? Any Idea..

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how to run mysql queries from bash command line.